# Exercise in Section 2.4 of Singer & Thorpe

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness, separation-axioms

I'm trying to solve the exercise in Section 2.4 of Singer & Thorpe, which is to prove that if $S$ is a compact Hausdorff topological space and $(U_n)_{n \in \Bbb N}$ be a family of dense open sets, then $\bigcap_n U_n \neq \emptyset$.  Actually, a similar result is shown (Theorem 2.4.2) where $S$ is a complete metric space.  In its proof one constructs a Cauchy sequence $(s_n)_n$ such that $s_n \in \bigcap_{k=0}^n U_n$, whose limit turns out to reside in $\bigcap_n U_n$.

In solving the exercise, I naturally imitate the proof of Theorem 2.4.2.  I can actually construct $(s_n)_n$ such that $s_n \in \bigcap_{k=0}^n U_n$, but I don't know how to make it convergent, because I don't know the "sizes" of open sets that $s_n$ resides in.  I would be grateful if you suggest a hint to the exercise.

Comment: Have you actually checked that $\bigcap\limits_{k=0}^n U_k\neq\emptyset$? You won't necessarily have a convergent sequence, but can you prove that it has a convergent subsequence?

Comment: @TedShifrin can one say some subsequence is convergent even if the space is not metric?

Comment: Actually, I would not proceed by constructing a sequence. I don't have Singer and Thorpe here at home, but perhaps you should consider the following lemma (perhaps they've proved it?): If $C_k$ are closed sets in a compact space with the property that $\bigcap\limits_{k=0}^n C_k\neq\emptyset$ for every $n$, then $\bigcap\limits_{k=0}^\infty C_k\neq\emptyset$.